Image file cannot resize the width
I don't know why I set in my container or Image.file the height and width with a BoxFit.fill and it's not working
     Stack(
        children: [
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              [...]

              Padding(
                padding: ...,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                      [...]
                      Container(
                        height: 150,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        color: Colors.red,
                        child: Image.file(
                          File(...),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),

          [...]
        ],
      ),


//////////// UPDATE :
I want that my image width cover all the container red. But i tried in differents ways and its not working :
                    Container(
                      height: 150,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,            
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: FittedBox(
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        child: Image.file(
                          File(...),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 150,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Image.file(
                        File(...),
                        height: 150,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 150,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: FileImage(
                            File(...),
                          ),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),



what about wrapping the Image with a FittedBox ?

@A-E its the same if i use it

Your problem isn't clear to me honestly. It would be great if you could edit your question to describe the issue better and clarify what you expect. Thanks.

you can also provide size in Image.file(height:, size goes up

You can try this code
    Container(
height : 200.0,
width : 200.0,
decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage(
            'assets/images/bg.png',
          ),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
color:Colors.red,),
child: Text("Hello World"),
),

I hope this can work for you. This will show your image inside your red container.
